# Question on 2-chain on $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-topology, differential-forms

Let $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$ be a simplex, with $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$. How can I show that exists a $2$-chain $\sigma$ on $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\partial\sigma=\gamma$.

Can I use this result to prove that an closed $C^{\infty}$ $1$-form $\alpha$ on $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$ is exact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first fact, it's enough to know that $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{0\}$ is simply connected, thus it has a  trivial first singular homology group: it follows that each 1-chain is the boundary of a 2-chain.

Comment: I'm not allow to use homology groups to solve this question. Can I solve without homology?

Comment: Consider a two simplex which performs your loop at each of the three sides, its boundary is what you need.